# video storing and synchronous streaming software

Tags: video, cloud-storage, hadoop, binary-data

I need some software solution for video storing. I will have a few IP cameras which has to stream into disks. This so called database records those streams.On demand I should be able to stream any of these videos or or few of them. Just do not want to merge video before recording, should be separate streams.

I have been investigating Hadoop. If Hadoop could do that, then it is also possible to store sensor input as well with it.

All suggestions welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Hadoop might be an answer: You could find some information in this link.

[video storing and synchronous streaming software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17772/video-storing-and-synchronous-streaming-software)